# Gremlin HA Configuration

Tags: gremlin-server, ongdb

**Versions**:

Neo4j: 3.2.3

Gremlin Server: 3.4.0

ext/neo4j-gremlin/plugin-info.txt

```
org.apache.tinkerpop:neo4j-gremlin:3.4.0
```

---

**Neo4J Instance 1**

```
docker run --name=instance1 \
    --publish=7474:7474 \
    --publish=7687:7687 \
    --publish=5001:5001 \
    --publish=6001:6001 \
    --net=cluster --hostname=instance1 \
    --volume=/home/admin-12/Downloads/TEST23:/data \
    --env=NEO4J_dbms_mode=HA --env=NEO4J_ha_server__id=1 \
    --env=NEO4J_ha_host_coordination=instance1:5001 --env=NEO4J_ha_host_data=instance1:6001 \
    --env=NEO4J_ha_initial__hosts=instance1:5001,instance2:5001,192.168.1.4:5003 \
    --env=NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes \
    neo4j:3.2.3-enterprise
```

**Neo4j Instance 2**

```
docker run --name=instance2 \
    --publish=8475:7474 \
    --publish=8688:7687 \
    --publish=5002:5001 \
    --publish=6002:6001 \
    --net=cluster --hostname=instance2 \
    --volume=/home/admin-12/Downloads/TEST24:/data \
    --env=NEO4J_dbms_mode=HA --env=NEO4J_ha_server__id=2 \
    --env=NEO4J_ha_host_coordination=instance2:5001 --env=NEO4J_ha_host_data=instance2:6001 \
    --env=NEO4J_ha_initial__hosts=instance1:5001,instance2:5001,192.168.1.4:5003 \
    --env=NEO4J_ACCEPT_LICENSE_AGREEMENT=yes \
    neo4j:3.2.3-enterprise
```

**ongdb-empty.properties**

```
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph
gremlin.neo4j.directory=/tmp/neo4j.server1
gremlin.neo4j.conf.ha.server_id=3
gremlin.neo4j.conf.ha.initial_hosts=localhost:5001\,localhost:5002\,localhost:5003
gremlin.neo4j.conf.ha.host.coordination=localhost:5003
gremlin.neo4j.conf.ha.host.data=localhost:6001
```

**gremlin-server-ongdb.yaml**

```
host: localhost
port: 8182
scriptEvaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
graphs: {
  graph: conf/ongdb-empty.properties}
scriptEngines: {
  gremlin-groovy: {
    plugins: { org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.jsr223.Neo4jGremlinPlugin: {},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ImportGremlinPlugin: {classImports: [java.lang.Math], methodImports: [java.lang.Math#*]},
               org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin: {files: [scripts/empty-sample.groovy]}}}}
serializers:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV3d0] }}            # application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GryoMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { serializeResultToString: true }}                                                                      # application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+gryo-stringd
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.structure.TinkerIoRegistryV3d0] }}        # application/json
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1 }                                                                                                           # application/vnd.graphbinary-v1.0
processors:
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor, config: { sessionTimeout: 28800000 }}
  - { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor, config: { cacheExpirationTime: 600000, cacheMaxSize: 1000 }}
metrics: {
  consoleReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000},
  csvReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000, fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv},
  jmxReporter: {enabled: true},
  slf4jReporter: {enabled: true, interval: 180000}}
strictTransactionManagement: false
idleConnectionTimeout: 0
keepAliveInterval: 0
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferLowWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
ssl: {
  enabled: false}
```

---

Neo4j Server seems to start fine but gremlin crashes

```
[INFO] GremlinServer - 3.4.0
         \,,,/
         (o o)
-----oOOo-(3)-oOOo-----

[INFO] GremlinServer - Configuring Gremlin Server from conf/gremlin-server-ongdb.yaml
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics ConsoleReporter configured with report interval=180000ms
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics CsvReporter configured with report interval=180000ms to fileName=/tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics JmxReporter configured with domain= and agentId=
[INFO] MetricManager - Configured Metrics Slf4jReporter configured with interval=180000ms and loggerName=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.Settings$Slf4jReporterMetrics
[WARN] DefaultGraphManager - Graph [graph] configured at [conf/ongdb-empty.properties] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph]
java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph]
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:82)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:70)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.lambda$new$0(DefaultGraphManager.java:57)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntrySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:671)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.<init>(DefaultGraphManager.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:80)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:122)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:78)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /tmp/neo4j.server1
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:209)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.ha.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.<init>(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabase.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory.java:71)
    at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:193)
    at org.neo4j.tinkerpop.api.impl.Neo4jFactoryImpl.newGraphDatabase(Neo4jFactoryImpl.java:46)
    at org.neo4j.tinkerpop.api.Neo4jFactory$Builder.open(Neo4jFactory.java:32)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph.<init>(Neo4jGraph.java:125)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph.open(Neo4jGraph.java:139)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin@1027a658' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Conversation-response mapping:
{3/13#=ResponseFuture{conversationId='3/13#', initiatedByMessageType=join, response=null}}".
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:444)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:205)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Conversation-response mapping:
{3/13#=ResponseFuture{conversationId='3/13#', initiatedByMessageType=join, response=null}}
    at org.neo4j.cluster.statemachine.StateMachineProxyFactory$ResponseFuture.get(StateMachineProxyFactory.java:315)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin.joinByConfig(ClusterJoin.java:143)
    at org.neo4j.cluster.client.ClusterJoin.start(ClusterJoin.java:82)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:434)
    ... 29 more
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
[INFO] ServerGremlinExecutor - Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing GremlinScriptEngines instances.
[ERROR] DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager - Could not create GremlinScriptEngine for gremlin-groovy
java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.lambda$createGremlinScriptEngine$16(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:464)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.createGremlinScriptEngine(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:450)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:219)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.lambda$getEngineByName$0(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:57)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:371)
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.lambda$createGremlinScriptEngine$16(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:460)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:687)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:369)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:67)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:309)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:45)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:664)
    ... 27 more
[WARN] ServerGremlinExecutor - Could not initialize gremlin-groovy GremlinScriptEngine as init script could not be evaluated
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: gremlin-groovy is not an available GremlinScriptEngine
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:375)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:1934)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.lambda$new$4(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:141)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:559)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:136)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:122)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:86)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: gremlin-groovy is not an available GremlinScriptEngine
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.registerLookUpInfo(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:95)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: judging from `GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.neo4j.structure.Neo4jGraph]` i'd guess that you don't have some dependencies on Gremlin Server's path. did you `bin/gremlin-server.sh install` those?

Comment: i did that install, re-trying the whole process and updating the post

Comment: i have not installed any plugin inside neo4j server, is something like that required?

Comment: no neo4j plugins should be needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Neo4j is not running in [embedded mode](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#connecting-embedded) within the Gremlin Server JVM, you would need to either (1) configure Gremlin Server in [Neo4j HA mode](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#_high_availability_configuration) effectively making it a node in the cluster or (2) use [neo4j-gremlin-bolt](https://github.com/SteelBridgeLabs/neo4j-gremlin-bolt) which would let you connect to Neo4j directly over the Bolt protocol.

Comment: tried the whole thing again with neo4j 3.2.3 and also edited the question. thanks

Comment: well....you're getting closer. at this point it just seems like you have some environmental configuration problem still amiss. i would focus on examining the stacktrace starting with "Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /tmp/neo4j.server1" and trying to resolve from there. i'm guessing that your local system with Gremlin Server isn't reaching the docker containers??

Comment: if i were you i would try to validate that HA works for you with just Gremlin Server instances on different ports as described in the documentation. if that's working then you can almost certainly know that you have a docker problem to sort out

Comment: 3 gremlin servers with HA config seems to work fine (for some odd reason it did fail first few times with same error, might be some random problem). also data added at ha1 is being viewed at h2 and h3. might be something to do with docker then. maybe i should just install neo4j on host and try it

Comment: It is a docker problem, works fine with direct host neo4j